# In browser video chat using existing services

Tags: api, video

I'm trying to set up in browser video chat for a web application. Unfortunately I don't think my servers would be able to handle it. Is there any way I can 'outsource' this to existing services such as the Hangouts feature in Google+, the new video chat in Facebook or the Skype API. If yes, which would you recommend and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TokBox makes it easy to add video chat to your site using either the
>   OpenTok API or OpenTok Widgets.

http://www.tokbox.com

Looks promising, haven't used it myself (need a self-hosted solution).